# FILTER range must be a single row or a single column. when trying to apply a condition across several columns at once

Tags: google-sheets

Here is a regular filter function that works as expected:

```
=filter(
data!$A$2:$A,
date!$D$2:$D>=$A$16,
data!$D$2:$D<=$B$16,
data!$EC$2:$EC=$A23
)
```

This returns the subset of values in `data!$A$2:$A` that match the conditions. Great.

I would like to add a condition to a range of columns, that all that `data!$CD$2:$CN` are all equal to one. Tried:

```
=filter(
data!$A$2:$A,
date!$D$2:$D>=$A$16,
data!$D$2:$D<=$B$16,
data!$EC$2:$EC=$A23,
data!$CD$2:$CN=1
)
```

Then tried:

```
=filter(
data!$A$2:$A,
date!$D$2:$D>=$A$16,
data!$D$2:$D<=$B$16,
data!$EC$2:$EC=$A23,
sum(data!$CD$2:$CN)=11 # there's 11 columns in this range
)
```

I get the error above. I could manually add a condition for each of the 11 columns:

```
=filter(
data!$A$2:$A,
date!$D$2:$D>=$A$16,
data!$D$2:$D<=$B$16,
data!$EC$2:$EC=$A23,
data!$CD$2:$CD=1,
data!$CE$2:$CE=1,
... lost more in here all the way to ...
data!$CN$2:$CN=1
)
```

But that's going to get pretty repetitive.

Is there a way to filter across a range of columns, in this case I want to filter to only include rows where everything in `data!$CD$2:$CN` equals 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MMULT` function to combine multiple columns into one criteria.

Ex:

[image]

In your case it would be:

```
=FILTER(data!$A$2:$A,MMULT(--(data!$CD$2:$CN=1),{1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1})=11)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot.

Comment: Interesting syntax there with the two dashes `MMULT(--` what's going on there? Am reading docs https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292

Comment: @DougFir it is way to convert bool to int value.

Comment: you can replace `{1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1}` by `sequence(columns(data!$CD$2:$CN),1,1,0)`