# How To Remove Blanks From Dynamic Multi-Columns Stacked/Vertically Merged into One Column with FILTER or QUERY in One Formula In Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got multiple (21) sets of 2 columns to put into one set of 2 columns, vertically stacked with no blanks in between.

The problem is that the 21 sets of 2 columns are dynamic (they have no predefined number of rows) and thus have variable numbers of blanks at their ends.

I've tried using the filter method below to filter out blanks, but it return an error that only one column per array is allowed.

### 21 Sets of 2 Columns To Put Into 1 Set of 2 Columns With FILTER Formula (Not Working):

```
=arrayformula(
FILTER(
{IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,55)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BF4+'Sheet1'!BH3-1,55)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,63)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BK2+'Sheet1'!BK3-1,63)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,65)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BM2+'Sheet1'!BM3-1,65)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,67)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BO2+'Sheet1'!BO3-1,67)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,69)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BQ2+'Sheet1'!BQ3-1,69)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,71)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BS2+'Sheet1'!BS3-1,71)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,73)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BU2+'Sheet1'!BU3-1,73)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,75)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BW2+'Sheet1'!BW3-1,75)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,77)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BY2+'Sheet1'!BY3-1,77)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,79)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CA2+'Sheet1'!CA3-1,79)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,81)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CC2+'Sheet1'!CC3-1,81)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,83)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CE2+'Sheet1'!CE3-1,83)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,85)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CG2+'Sheet1'!CG3-1,85)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,87)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CI2+'Sheet1'!CI3-1,87)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,89)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CK2+'Sheet1'!CK3-1,89)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,91)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CM2+'Sheet1'!CM3-1,91)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,93)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CO2+'Sheet1'!CO3-1,93)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,95)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CQ2+'Sheet1'!CQ3-1,95)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,97)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CS2+'Sheet1'!CS3-1,97)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,99)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CU2+'Sheet1'!CU3-1,99)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,101)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CW2+'Sheet1'!CW3-1,101)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ))},
LEN(
{IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,55)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BF4+'Sheet1'!BH3-1,55)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,63)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BK2+'Sheet1'!BK3-1,63)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,65)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BM2+'Sheet1'!BM3-1,65)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,67)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BO2+'Sheet1'!BO3-1,67)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,69)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BQ2+'Sheet1'!BQ3-1,69)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,71)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BS2+'Sheet1'!BS3-1,71)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,73)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BU2+'Sheet1'!BU3-1,73)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,75)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BW2+'Sheet1'!BW3-1,75)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,77)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BY2+'Sheet1'!BY3-1,77)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,79)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CA2+'Sheet1'!CA3-1,79)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,81)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CC2+'Sheet1'!CC3-1,81)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,83)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CE2+'Sheet1'!CE3-1,83)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,85)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CG2+'Sheet1'!CG3-1,85)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,87)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CI2+'Sheet1'!CI3-1,87)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,89)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CK2+'Sheet1'!CK3-1,89)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,91)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CM2+'Sheet1'!CM3-1,91)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,93)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CO2+'Sheet1'!CO3-1,93)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,95)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CQ2+'Sheet1'!CQ3-1,95)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,97)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CS2+'Sheet1'!CS3-1,97)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,99)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CU2+'Sheet1'!CU3-1,99)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,101)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CW2+'Sheet1'!CW3-1,101)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ))}
)))
```

Removing the FILTER Function, I've next tried the QUERY function instead as below (following this tutorial: [QUERY To Remove blanks](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/stack-data-in-google-sheets/)), but it returns an error that BI has no content (because it is the output range/the cell the QUERY function is in).

### 21 Sets of 2 Columns To Put Into 1 Set of 2 Columns With QUERY Formula (Not Working):

```
=QUERY(
{IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,55)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BF4+'Sheet1'!BH3-1,56)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,63)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BK2+'Sheet1'!BK3-1,64)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,65)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BM2+'Sheet1'!BM3-1,66)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,67)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BO2+'Sheet1'!BO3-1,68)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,69)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BQ2+'Sheet1'!BQ3-1,70)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,71)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BS2+'Sheet1'!BS3-1,72)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,73)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BU2+'Sheet1'!BU3-1,74)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,75)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BW2+'Sheet1'!BW3-1,76)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,77)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BY2+'Sheet1'!BY3-1,78)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,79)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CA2+'Sheet1'!CA3-1,80)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,81)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CC2+'Sheet1'!CC3-1,82)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,83)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CE2+'Sheet1'!CE3-1,84)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,85)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CG2+'Sheet1'!CG3-1,86)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,87)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CI2+'Sheet1'!CI3-1,88)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,89)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CK2+'Sheet1'!CK3-1,90)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,91)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CM2+'Sheet1'!CM3-1,92)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,93)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CO2+'Sheet1'!CO3-1,94)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,95)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CQ2+'Sheet1'!CQ3-1,96)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,97)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CS2+'Sheet1'!CS3-1,98)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,99)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CU2+'Sheet1'!CU3-1,100)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,101)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CW2+'Sheet1'!CW3-1,102)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ))},"where BI is not null")
```

Finally I've got the needed result by using the same idea but with the QUERY Function in a separate cell applied over the stacked with blanks output (in BI), as below.

### 21 Sets of 2 Columns Stacked into 1 Set Of 2 Columns With Blanks Formula in Columns BI:BJ (Working with QUERY in separate cell below)):

```
=arrayformula(
{IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,55)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BF4+'Sheet1'!BH3-1,56)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,63)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BK2+'Sheet1'!BK3-1,64)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,65)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BM2+'Sheet1'!BM3-1,66)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,67)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BO2+'Sheet1'!BO3-1,68)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,69)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BQ2+'Sheet1'!BQ3-1,70)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,71)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BS2+'Sheet1'!BS3-1,72)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,73)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BU2+'Sheet1'!BU3-1,74)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,75)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BW2+'Sheet1'!BW3-1,76)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,77)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!BY2+'Sheet1'!BY3-1,78)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,79)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CA2+'Sheet1'!CA3-1,80)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,81)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CC2+'Sheet1'!CC3-1,82)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,83)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CE2+'Sheet1'!CE3-1,84)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,85)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CG2+'Sheet1'!CG3-1,86)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,87)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CI2+'Sheet1'!CI3-1,88)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,89)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CK2+'Sheet1'!CK3-1,90)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,91)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CM2+'Sheet1'!CM3-1,92)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,93)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CO2+'Sheet1'!CO3-1,94)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,95)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CQ2+'Sheet1'!CQ3-1,96)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,97)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CS2+'Sheet1'!CS3-1,98)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,99)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CU2+'Sheet1'!CU3-1,100)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ));
IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(4,101)&":"&ADDRESS('Sheet1'!CW2+'Sheet1'!CW3-1,102)),SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(REPT(12, 2), 1), 2, ))}
)
```

### QUERY in a separate cell (BK) (Working with separate Stacked ARRAYFORMULA above):

`=QUERY(BI2:BJ, "Select * where BJ<>''")`

That is working, but I'm wondering if there's a better/simpler way to do it without the separate cell solution, and if possible without that much bigger of a formula than the FILTER Formula one.

If possible, what would be the way to use the FILTER function with multiple columns?

(I don't understand why the FILTER function doesn't work with multiple columns in my case as each of the 21 'double columns' has the same data on both columns (the blanks are only at the end and not randomly scattered within the data))

If the FILTER function cannot work on multiple columns, what other simpler way/function-s to remove blanks than with the QUERY function in separate cell?

If only the QUERY function would work, how to use it within in a single formula with the above example?

Many thanks for your help!

I've looked at these other close questions and answers [FILTER range must be a single row or a single column. when trying to apply a condition across several columns at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69327734/filter-range-must-be-a-single-row-or-a-single-column-when-trying-to-apply-a-con?rq=1)  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133351/filter-and-match-multiple-columns-in-google-sheets but it doesn't seem to be usable to remove blanks of dynamic ranges.

Comment: Can you share a simplified copy of your spreadsheet ?

Comment: is the first column the same for all the 21 sets? and it's just the second that's different?

Comment: Here is a spreadsheet created specifically to answer this question. I took a guess at what your Sheet1 Looks like but you should make your own by pasting so that folks here can better understand what you're after.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qRU9Pi33pObsaNFeJUfOHVtcKdbDKLTF65FNrkKUYfM/edit#gid=0

Comment: if you are trying to stack multiple pairs of columns, into a single pair of columns, then in the `{curly brackets}` you can put the ranges, separated by `;` (semicolons), then select both columns where the first column does not have a blank, with formula like this: `=QUERY({BC4:BD; BF4:BG; BI4:BJ}, "Select Col1, Col2 Where Col1 Is Not Null")`

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies! I've been busy on another project but I'll try to build a simple version of my sheet asap. Looks like Mr Shane's got a simple solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Seems to me this could be done with a relatively short single array formula. Share the sample spreadsheet, and I'll take another look.